# Animate leafing through?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to animate leafing through views to look like a real book leafing through?

Comment: look at some of the eBook apps in the app store.  It has been done but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the option of using CoreAnimation to animate any view.  For this purpose, it could become quite complex though.

There is a native animation for UIView that peels it up from the corner like a page.  This kind of animation is more akin to leafing through a notepad than a book but it may just serve the purpose your looking for.  If you wanted to do this it would look something like this:

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The duration of the animation can be set to whatever you like.